# How can I reset a variable in a loop in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop

I am writing a number-guessing game for my Computer Science 1100 class, one part of which is to print the number of attempts the player takes at guessing the target number.  I've defined a variable `tries` to track that; the program increments it by one every time the player makes a guess.

The game restarts after the player guesses the number correctly, and at that point I want to reset the `tries` counter.  I can't figure out how to do that, however, because the program increments `tries` each time the number is guessed.  How can I do it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Q2 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
      Random r = new Random();
      System.out.println("Welcome to the Number Guessing Game");
      int x=0;//defining x for later
      int tries = 1;//defining tries for later
      while (x!=-1) { 
         int y = r.nextInt(101);//defining random number 0-100
         System.out.print("Guess a number between 0 and 100 or enter -1 to quit: ");
         x=kbd.nextInt();//redefining x
         x=kbd.nextInt();//redefining x
         for (int i=1;x!=-1&&x!=y;i=1) {//for loop
               if (x<-1||x>100) {//illegal condition
                  System.out.print("Out of bounds. Try again: ");
               }
               else if (x>y) {//input greater than random condition
                  System.out.print("The number is lower. Try again: ");
               }
               else if (y>x) {//random greater than input condition
                  System.out.print("The number is higher. Try again: ");
               }
               x = kbd.nextInt();//redefining x
               tries+=i;//defining pattern for tries
         }
         if (x==y) {//input=random condition
            System.out.println("Congratulations! You guessed the number in " + tries + " tries");
         }
      }
      if (x==-1) {//quit condition
         System.out.print("Thank you for playing the game!!");
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: Wherever u r telling "u guessed it right", also tell tries to restart.

Comment: You are probably overthinking this.  You likely just want to put `tries = 0` -- or maybe `tries = -1` -- in the right place.

Comment: This is kind of hard to answer without your existing code, but two nested while loops comes to mind.

Comment: As stated by @kcraigie, make sure to include whatever code is relevant toward the question. When in doubt, include more versus less. The key bit to keep in mind is to ***help others help you***.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### a) Change the scope of your variable

Variables are only available in the scope they are defined in. For example

```
while (something) { // all code inside the loop is in an inner scope
  int variable = 42;
  // variable is accessible here
}
// variable is not accessible here
```

This means, every time the while-loop performs one iteration, variable is newly created. It is a good practice to only define variables in the scope they actually have a meaning (in this case in the while-loop).

### b) Assign the variable every time anew

Another way would be to reset the variable each time it is necessary. This would result in such a design:

```
int variable; // variable is defined outside the inner scope
while (something) {
  variable = 42;
  // some code that changes variable's value
}
```

Comment: got it, thanksa lot. just had to define tries as 1 again :P

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to encapsulate your guessing game into it's own method, which will re-initialize all variables when called, and create an `if` condition inside of your loop if the guess is correct.

```
private static void guessingGame() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    double randomNum = Math.random();
    double tries = 0, guess = 0;

    do while (!(guess == randomNum) {
        System.in("What is your guess? ");
        guess = scanner.nextDouble();
        tries++;

        if (guess == randomNum) {
           System.out.println("Guessed correctly in " + tries + " tries.");
           tries = 0;
        }
    }
}

public static void main() {
   guessingGame();
}
```